# What data should I save in my database for my website?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm going to be launching a site soon and I'm using a MySQL database to store data. I want to make sure I'm not forgetting to save anything that could be useful later. I currently have two tables, `users` and `events`. `users` is just the registered users of the site, and `events` are events that users can create on a schedule. Here's what I store for each table:

`users`: `id` (int(11)), `email` (varchar(75)), `password` (varchar(10000)), `first` (varchar(35)), `last` (varchar(35)), `reg_date` (timestamp), (a few other things)

`events`: `id` (int(11)), `description` (text), `day` (int(11)), `month` (int(11)), `year` (int(11)), `hour` (int(11)), `minute` (int(11)), `creator` (int(11))

Do you guys think I should add anything? Any suggestions in general for my tables? I'm pretty new to MySQL.

**Edit:** I'm also adding a `created` row to my `events` table with the date the table was created. I'm also probably going to add a `edited` row where I will put the old description should the user edit the event (not sure though).

Comment: We aren't managing your database, you store what you want. You can always alter the tables to add columns later.

Comment: @cricket_007 I know, but if I add them later I won't have that data stored for users that have already signed up/events that were already created.

Comment: Then add a where clause to filter out the nulls when you query for your events. I'm just saying your question is very broad. My 2 cents, though, use a timestamp for your events like you are for user registration.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am, I included that in an edit, thanks.

Comment: The list of things you can add to a DB is endless. You should add whatever you are having the users submit (also don't store passwords in plain text). If you need to add a column in the future just set the data to `null` or empty for users that didn't have and account for that in the code being used to access it.

Comment: You'll probably want to use a [DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) rather than spelling it all out.

Comment: @Schwern I'm considering going with that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have covered all the basics, other itmes commonly included in user tables;

- Username, or preferred display name
- Gender, which can also be inferred from Title (Mr, Mrs, Miss, etc)
- Address, people tend to overcomplicate this, unless you really need to know street names, zip codes, etc explicitly just save the whole thing into a text/blob field which can be used for mail outs, etc
- Contact Phone/Mobile

**Important Security Fields,**

- Iam not sure why you need 1,000 character passwords, I suspect you may not be hashing, this is not good, please hash!
- Consider adding an additional 'salt' column, using unique salts significantly improves password security
- Track failed login attempts since last successful login

**Information you can gather automatically, which may help with marketing**

- Last login IP - can be used to determine users geolocation
- Login count, how active is this user
- Last login date, useful for security and identifying stale accounts, but also makes it easy to see how many logins you have had in the past day, week, etc

Comment: I concur about the address. Either store it as a single text field and parse it (there are several APIs and libraries to parse addresses) OR if it's goingt o be an important part of your application make each address its own table. All or nothing.

Comment: @harvey I don't want to limit the length of users' passwords (max is actually 10,000 characters), and yes, they are hashed with SHA256 (then encrypted with bcrypt). I also think I'm going to track failed login attempts, IP, login count, and date last logged in like you suggested — thanks for the ideas!

Comment: @Schwern I won't need users' addresses for this site so I'd rather not ask them for it/store it if I don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get this out of the way right now, **DO NOT STORE THE PASSWORD**! This is how passwords get stolen. Only store a properly salted hash of the password. Use either the built in [SHA2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2) or, better yet, [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

[Read all about how to do it right here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

---

Some notes about types.

- Don't use TIMESTAMP, use DATETIME. TIMESTAMP is quirky and has a limited range of 1970 to 2038.
- Store the date in the events table as a single DATETIME column. This will take less space and you can use [MySQL's (weird and quirky but better than nothing) date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html).
- Consider using UNSIGNED BIGINT for all your ids, especially the events. 2 billion seems like a lot, but it sucks when you run out. I've had it happen.
- Don't bother with limited length VARCHARs, just use TEXT. It all takes up about the same amount of disk space. Your data schema should not be enforcing business rules.

Comment: I hash it with SHA256 then encrypt it with 15 rounds of bcrypt, then store that. Do you think that's safe enough?

I'll also switch to DATETIME, thanks for the heads up. Can't I just convert the INTs to UNSIGNED BIGINT later if I need to? I'll also switch to TEXT as per your suggestion.

Comment: @busterroni There is no need to do multiple rounds of bcrypt or use two hashing algorithms, bcrypt has a "cost" which does `2^cost` iterations. Set the cost so it takes as long as you're willing to have users wait to log in, at least 100ms is recommended. Make sure you use a good salt, `/dev/random` is good. I don't know what language you're using, but [PHP's password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) does all this for you. I'd recommend you post your code for review as another question.

Comment: @busterroni As for switching IDs later, you can, but you'll have to get every id and *every table that uses that id* and then `ALTER TABLE` on all those tables and hope it doesn't take too long and hope nobody else stored IDs as 32 bit integers. Or you can spend 4 bytes per row now and be done with it. It's one of those "will only be a problem in a few years and if we're a success" trade-offs.

Comment: I use SHA256 because bcrypt (the Python version at least) has a maximum length of 72 characters and I don't want to limit users to 72 character passwords, so I hash the passwords into SHA256 then use bcrypt on that. I'm pretty sure bcrypt generates the salt for me. By 15 rounds I meant a cost of 15, I only hash it once.

Comment: @busterroni 72 characters is plenty long for a password, at that point with bcrypt it's more about your good salt and their good password picking. From a user's perspective, simply truncate their password. Double hashing *probably* won't hurt anything, but I don't see that being recommended. When it comes to cryptography I'd run any changes to the standard procedure past a cryptographer. I am not a cryptographer. Perhaps ask at [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I'll double check with a cryptographer, but from what I've read and heard it should be safe. I'd rather not limit users to 72 character passwords if they choose to be more secure. I also plan on sharing my code for saving the passwords to make sure it's secure.